# Invoke a service from a "serverless" fsm (Xstate)

Tags: node.js, serverless, xstate

I'm using xsate on a Node.JS backend.
Here is the current flow :

- State is rehydrated (Initialized or fetched from DB)
- Event is sent to the FSM
- State is serialized to DB

Here is some pseudo code

```js
const state  = db.fetch(flowId) ?? machine.initialState;
 // Use State.create() to restore state from a plain object
const previousState = State.create<DefaultContext, MyEvent>(stateDefinition);
// Use machine.resolveState() to resolve the state definition to a new State instance relative to the machine
const resolvedState = machine.resolveState(previousState);
const interpreter = interpret(machine).start(resolvedState);
onst newState: State<DefaultContext, MyEvent, any, Typestate<DefaultContext>> = interpreter.send(event);
db.saveState(flowId, newState);
```

My question is :
Is it possible to Invoke a Promise ?

I would like to keep my  FSM "alive" if I have pending promises.
The goal is to modify the context based on the promise result.
Is there some hook I could use ?

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same use case as you. So what I do is add an extra property to context, say `waitingAsync`. Set it to `true` on the state entry, and set it to `false` on done.

Follow the [Invoking Promises example](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/communication.html#invoking-promises) with some modifications:

```
// ...
loading: {
  // set waitingAsync to true
  entry: assign((context) => ({...context, waitingAsync: true})),
  invoke: {
    id: 'getUser',
    src: (context, event) => fetchUser(context.userId),
    onDone: {
      target: 'success',
      actions: [
        assign({ user: (context, event) => event.data })
        // set waitingAsync to false
        assign((context) => ({...context, waitingAsync: false}))
      ]
    },
  }
},
// ...
```

Then you can use the [waitFor](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/interpretation.html#waitfor) helper to wait until the promise is done.

```
const interpreter = interpret(machine).start();
interpreter.send(event);
await waitFor(interpreter, (state) => !state.context.waitingAsync);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the new [`waitFor(...)`](https://github.com/statelyai/xstate/pull/3190) helper in the latest version of XState to asyncronously wait for a state machine to reach some condition, like a specific state.

In your situation, the predicate would be something like `state.matches('yourSuccessState')`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info.
But it wont work in my case.
I have a generic fsm runner. So I cannot wait for a specific state. The runner is agnostic.

I Just want to be able to wait for "invoked" promise to be resolved.